# $41$-th derivative of $\sin(x^2-2x+2)$ at point $1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Problem: 
$$\frac{\mathrm d^{41}}{\mathrm dx^{41}}\sin(x^2-2x+2)$$

Can anyone help me with this because I tried to use General Leibniz rule(after I differentiate $\sin(x^2-2x+2)$) and I didn't get much better information and I also tried some proof by induction but also no success 
Without using Taylor.

Comment: Write $t = x-1$. Then you want the $41^{\text{st}}$ derivative of $\sin (t^2+1)$ at $0$.

Comment: $\sin(t^2+1)=\sin(t^2)\cos1+\cos(t^2)\sin1$

Comment: There is no need to compute anything. In terms of $t = x-1$, $\sin(t^2+1)$ is an even function in $t$, so all its derivatives of odd order vanish at $t = 0$.

Comment: This problem deserves an upvote +1

Comment: @achille hui Can you please prove that step?